# Can we further simplify this matrix equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $X_{n \times p}$ (rank $\leq p)$, $Y_{n \times q}$ is of rank $q$, $\Sigma_{q \times q}$ is of rank $q$ and $B_{q \times p}$ such that $Rank(J + B^TU^T) = q$ where $J = [0_{p\times q} | I_p]$ of rank $p$ and $U^T = [I_q | -C_{q \times p}]$ of rank $q$.

Can we solve the following equation for $B$ under two cases:

\begin{align}
X B \Sigma^{-1} B^T = Y\Sigma^{-1}B^T 
\end{align}

where $\Sigma = A + CB + B^TC^T + B^TDB$, where $A$ is symmetric and $D$ is symmetric and positive definite.

I can see two solutions here:

1. $B$ is a null matrix.
2. $B$ is full column rank.

Are there any other possibilities?

$X B \Sigma^{-1} B^T- Y\Sigma^{-1}B^T $ is the gradient of some complicated objective function. Is that mean the objective function is non-convex?

Because it is hard to compute the second derivative of the matrix to see whether it is convex or not.

Answer (score 1):

A mistake: $B\in M_{p,q}$.

Clearly, if the equation (1) $XB=Y$ has at least one solution, then the complete equation $(*)$ has at least a solution.

$(1)$ has a solution iff $XX^+Y=Y$ where $X^+$ is the Moore- Penrose inverse. cf.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Obtaining_all_solutions_of_a_linear_system

Then the general solution of $(1)$ is $B=X^+Y+(I-X^+X)W$ where $W\in M_{p,q}$ is arbitrary.

Notice also that, if $rank(B)=q$, then $(*)$ is equivalent to $(1)$ but that not implies that $(1)$ has a solution.